# When i ran bin/magento setup:di:compile command got an issue in pluginList.php and pluginListGenerator.php

Tags: magento2.4.5

I changed this line

```
$cacheId = implode('|', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "|" . $this->cacheId;
```

to like this

```
$cacheId = implode('-', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "-" . $this->cacheId;
```

in both pages but still I'm facing this issue

```
Warning: Undefined property: Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList::$scopePriorityScheme in C:\xampp
  \htdocs\magento-new-project\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList.php on line 220
```

can't able to resolve those issues in Magento2.4.5